# Python\Marshmallow: TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls_or_instance'

Tags: python, marshmallow

I defined in some class **Class1** the following list:

```
class Class1(BaseModel):   # BaseModel is the ORM's base model

    _name = ""
    _year = 0
    .....

    VALUE_LIST = ['a', 'b', 'c]

    def __init__(self, name, year, ........):
        self._name = name
        self._year = year
        ......
```

and in another file, **file_x.py**, I imported the class and used list like this:

```
from myproj.models.class1 import Class1

_value = fields.List(
        attribute='value', data_key='value',
        required=False, allow_none=True, validate=validate.OneOf(Class1.VALUE_LIST, 
              error='value is not allowed'))
```

Then, when I run a tests I get:

```
ImportError while loading conftest '/home/ubuntu/PycharmProjects/xmaker_application_manager/xmaker_mgr_app/test/conftest.py'.
__init__.py:5: in <module>
    from xmaker_mgr_app.controllers.user_controller import UserOperator
../controllers/user_controller.py:5: 
in <module>
    from xmaker_mgr_app.bl.user_operator import UserOperator
../bl/user_operator.py:8:
 in <module>
    from xmaker_mgr_app.bl.file_x import UserSchema
../bl/file_x.py:177:
 in <module>
    class Class1Schema(ma.ModelSchema):
../bl/file_x.py:211:
 in Class1Schema
    required=False, allow_none=True, validate=validate.OneOf(Class1.VALUE_LIST, error='value is not allowed'))
E   TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cls_or_instance'
```

How should I fix that?

Answer (score 2):

Python is telling you that you are trying to call a function (in this case, constructor of class fields.List) which expects a positional argument named "cls_or_instance", but you did not provide it.

If you check how you are calling constructor of fields.List, you see that you have provided several arguments by their name (attribute, data_key, allow_none etc.), but there is no cls_or_instance among them.

You should be able to fix this either by `fields.List(x, ...)` or by `fields.List(cls_or_instance=x, ...)`. In this case, `x` is the value of parameter `cls_or_instance` and `...` is the stuff that you already have.

In either case, the documentation will tell you which arguments are mandatory, which are optional and what they must be.

Comment: Thank you jurez so much for your time. I edited like this: fields.List(cls_or_instance=x,
        attribute='....     but it says it does not recognize x. I am totally new to python and without a doubt missing something... I understand x should be replace with the value of cls_or_instance parameter. But where is this cls_or_instance parameter? I don;t have it in my class...

Comment: Maybe I found the answer with cls_or_instance=fields.Str() ....

Comment: Yes, like I said, `x` is the value that you must provide to the function. Read the documentation what the value should be - your code needs to define it. You can pass this value either as positional argument or as a named argument.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that I had to use fields.Str since the value is str and not list.

So

```
_value = fields.Str(
        attribute='value', data_key='value',
        required=False, allow_none=True, validate=validate.OneOf(Class1.VALUE_LIST, 
              error='value is not allowed'))
```